# Angular CLI deployment on Heroku

Tags: heroku, angular, production, angular-cli

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.angularonrails.com/deploy-angular-cli-webpack-project-heroku/) on how to deploy Angular CLI application to Heroku but ran into an error when trying to push to heroku remote.

Got the following:

```
> testas@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405
remote:        > ng build && mv dist/* .
remote:        
remote:        Could not start watchman; falling back to NodeWatcher for  file system events.
remote:        Visit http://ember-cli.com/user-guide/#watchman for more info.
remote:        Build failed.
remote:        The Broccoli Plugin: [Funnel] failed with:
remote:        Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'typings'
remote:        at Error (native)
remote:        at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:887:18)
remote:        at symlink (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:60:26)
remote:        at symlinkOrCopySync (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/symlink-or-copy/index.js:55:5)
remote:        at /tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:58:9
remote:        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
remote:        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
remote:        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
remote:        at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
remote:        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
remote:        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
remote:        
remote:        The broccoli plugin was instantiated at:
remote:        at Funnel.Plugin (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:10:31)
remote:        at new Funnel   (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/broccoli-funnel/index.js:44:10)
remote:        at Angular2App._buildInputTree (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:93:7)
remote:        at new Angular2App (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/broccoli/angular2-app.js:51:41)
remote:        at module.exports (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/angular-cli-build.js:10:10)
remote:        at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.setupBroccoliBuilder (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:55:19)
remote:        at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.init (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/models/builder.js:89:10)
remote:        at new Class (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/core-object/core-object.js:18:12)
remote:        at Class.module.exports.Task.extend.run (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/tasks/build.js:15:19)
remote:        at /tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/angular-cli/lib/commands/build.js:32:24
remote:        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
remote:        at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
remote:        at /tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:331:11
remote:        at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/tmp/build_96f718bcbe906771d313a2db03fa7405/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
remote:        at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
remote:        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Comment: Looks like you're using a non-Webpack version of Angular CLI. What does `ng -v` return? I would try `npm uninstall -g angular-cli` and then `npm install -g angular-cli@webpack`.

Comment: Yeah, that helped, thanks!

Comment: Okay, great. I added my comment as an answer so you can accept it if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm install -g angular-cli@webpack
```

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14 The latest version of Angular CLI seems to support webpack as standard

Comment: You're right, it does. This question/answer probably won't be an issue people have going forward.